# Having trouble implementing code pen into my project

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, ionic-framework

Here is the code pen:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zqjdRg

And I am using ionic framework to create my app. I have copy and pasted the html into my main.html file, the css into the style.css file, and the JS I added to the controller at first but also tried saving it into its own file cirlcebar.js in my js folder and adding the script to my index.html as follows:

```
  <script src="js/circlebar.js"></script>
```

Nothing is working

Comment: What is the exact problem?

Comment: do you have any errors in your console?

Comment: Sorry it took me so long to respond...I was having internet issues...the console only shows "tick — circlebar.js:12-1"...not an error just loggin in a tick